# unidentified php syntax error

Tags: php, syntax-error

I am trying to use a pre-written PHP autoloader and dreamweaver is stating that there is a syntax error. Can someone please explain what is causing the problem.

The lines which show as having syntax errors are
$autoloader = new static($dir, $ext);
spl_autoload_register([$autoloader, 'load']);

```
<?php

/**
 * A basic PSR style autoloader
 */
class AutoLoader
{
    protected $dir;
    protected $ext;

    public function __construct($dir, $ext = '.php')
    {
        $this->dir = rtrim($dir, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
        $this->ext = $ext;
    }

    public static function register($dir, $ext = '.php')
    {
        $autoloader = new static($dir, $ext);
        spl_autoload_register([$autoloader, 'load']);

        return $autoloader;
    }

    public function load($class)
    {
        $dir = $this->dir;

        if ($ns = $this->get_namespace($class)) {
            $dir .= DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $ns);
        }

        $inc_file = $dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$this->get_class($class).$this->ext;

        if (file_exists($inc_file)) {
            require_once $inc_file;
        }
    }

    // Borrowed from github.com/borisguery/Inflexible
    protected static function get_class($value)
    {
        $className = trim($value, '\\');

        if ($lastSeparator = strrpos($className, '\\')) {
            $className = substr($className, 1 + $lastSeparator);
        }

        return $className;
    }

    // Borrowed from github.com/borisguery/Inflexible
    public static function get_namespace($fqcn)
    {
        if ($lastSeparator = strrpos($fqcn, '\\')) {
            return trim(substr($fqcn, 0, $lastSeparator + 1), '\\');
        }

        return '';
    }
}
```

Comment: Please cut & paste the exact error messages you get, not just a paraphrase.

Comment: There is a syntax error on line 29. code hinting my not work until you correct this error

Answer (score 4):

```
spl_autoload_register([$autoloader, 'load']);
```

This array syntax is only valid as of PHP 5.4. If DreamWeaver is using an older version of PHP syntax rules, it will complain.

Comment: and it looks like `static::` -> `new static($dir, $ext)` is valid as of PHP 5.3 (http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php), so Dreamweaver might be < 5.3